# Python: an integer is required

Tags: python

Here is my code

```
def refresh(self,attachedSlotPos,srcSlotPos):
            attrSlot = [player.GetItemAttribute(attachedSlotPos, i) for i in
xrange(player.ATTRIBUTE_SLOT_MAX_NUM)]
```

Err:

```
0819 15:37:27441 ::   File "uiswitch.py", line 144, in refresh

0819 15:37:27441 :: TypeError
0819 15:37:27441 :: : 
0819 15:37:27441 :: an integer is required
```

How can i fix it? for python27

Comment: I'm going to guess that you can fix it by providing an integer?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in this line, then most likely the argument to `xrange()` isn't an integer.